# Need help splitting individual numbers from a starting number, then assign to integers

Tags: c#, base-conversion

So I am trying to split a starting number and then assign each of those numbers to their own integers that can then be used in some equations for example:

```
Int Starting_Number = 8056
Int Four = 8
Int Three = 0
Int Two = 5
Int One = 6
```

The Problem I have ran into is that I can't make 500+ individual integers to be assigned for my input(which is the max length of my text box).

And second I am trying to multiply each of those numbers by their power Using the Example numbers above and add them together (which is where I am not sure how to do without knowing the integer names that get assigned whether by me or by some another method in the question above):

```
Int One = 6^0 = 6*0 = 0
Int Two = 5^1 = 5*1 = 5
Int Three = 0^2 = 0*0 = 0
Int Four = 8^3 = 8*8*8 = 512
```

0+5+0+512 = 517
(Ending Number)Result

Hopefully I explained that well, I am using Visual Studios C# Windows form application.

Thanks in advance. P.S. I work long shifts probably wont see this for a day or so...

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. First you need to split the starting number into an array of some sort. You may do it multiple ways. Either convert the number into a string then the string into an array of char OR run a simple `for`, or `while`, each time deviding ur base number by 10 and storing the last digit, via `num % 10`, in a list/array of int. Then with multiplication simply can use `Math.Pow()` - first parameter is the digit, second is by how much you wish to power it. The second parameter can be gotten from `i`, when running `for` cikle to fit your need.

Comment: If you need more of a demo, i can upload a demo code for you to analize if the explonarion isint enough. if so - comment and tag me.

Comment: Sweet, thank you! I will give it a shot on my own to try and experiment while I learn, but if it starts to get to a point where I'm not getting anywhere then I will come back for the demo code. thank you again! :)

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
           int Starting_Number = 8056;
            char[] digits = Starting_Number.ToString().ToCharArray();
            int results = (int)digits.Select((x, i) => Math.Pow(10, digits.Length - i - 1) * int.Parse(x.ToString())).Sum();
```